# Write an IF (else) statement combined with refreshing WebBrowser in Visual Basic

Tags: html, vb.net

I have written code that searches for the keywords "visual basic help" on this page and clicks a link if it consists of these keywords.

But what I need to add is that if no link consists of these keywords, it has to refresh the page.

I think that I need to add an `If` statement but I'm not sure how, as this loop can go on and on and on until the keywords are found.

I have written this code:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://stackoverflow.com/")
For Each Mylink1 As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Links
    If Mylink1.OuterHtml.Contains("visual basic help") Then
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(Mylink1.GetAttribute("href"))
    End If
Next
```

But I need to rewrite this so that if no link on the WebBrowser's webpage consists of "visual basic help" it refreshes "https://stackoverflow.com/" and searches for "visual basic help" again.

Is anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should put that in the WebBrowser's `DocumentCompleted` event instead so that the code is run only when the whole webpage is downloaded.

Secondly, you could add a `Boolean` indicating wether a link has been found or not, then after the loop you can check if that `Boolean` was set to true. If not, you just refresh the WebBrowser.

To activate this using a button just add the EventHandler when checking for it, and remove it when a link was found.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString().ToLower() = "http://stackoverflow.com/" 'Making sure that we're on the correct page, to avoid constant updating while we are on another page.
        Dim LinkFound As Boolean = False 'Our boolean indicating wether a link has been found or not.

        For Each Mylink1 As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Links
            If Mylink1.OuterHtml.ToLower().Contains("visual basic help") Then 'ToLower() is making sure that the match is case-insensitive.
                LinkFound = True 'A link was found.
                WebBrowser1.Navigate(Mylink1.GetAttribute("href"))
                RemoveHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted 'Remove the handler to stop the checking for links.
                Exit For 'No more looping needed.
            End If

        Next

        If LinkFound = False Then
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(WebBrowser1.Url) 'No link was found, retry. Using Navigate so that DocumentCompleted will be continuously called.
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    AddHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted 'Add handler to the DocumentCompleted event so that it will execute the link checking code.
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com/")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi mate, thanks a lot for your reply. But I've got one other question, I want it to start if I click Button1, so how do I have to change the code? Because the page now only refreshes once (if there's no match)..

Comment: If you don't put it in `DocumentCompleted` it won't refresh according to my code. Use a boolean in the button too to indicate that you're starting it. But really, you need to use the DC event.

Comment: please check my code, I edited it in my original question, as I don't have enough characters left. @Visual

Comment: @F.Rippi I updated my answer. Copy-paste the code to ensure you get all changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm sorry that I changed your comment.. I'm new to all this, and thought that I was editing my original post. I appreciate it a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @F.Rippi You're welcome! Please mark my answer as the accepted answer by pressing the green tick on its left.

Comment: Visual Vincent, it's not working yet. Can I private message/chat/Twitter you? It's a bit more complicated than I thought, and I have not written the whole code of the project in this post, as I thought that that would be too complicated. Thank you. @Visual

Comment: I have to go now, but you can e-mail me. Look in my StackOverflow profile for my website, enter it and go in the "support" section.

Comment: Thank you, I'll e-mail you.